# Is there a way to disable 'Debug Log' option for React Native Vimeo Iframe?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile

[Debug Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK0b4.png)
So, I want to disable the option. I've tried to make `showDebug = {false}` but there is no such property available.

`showDebug = {false}` => Property 'showDebug' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LayoutProps'

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to turn off the React Native Vimeo Iframe's "Debug Log" feature. You must add the disableDebugLog prop to the Vimeo Iframe component in order to achieve this. This prop's value should to be set to true.

'Debug Log' can be turned off as follows, for example:

```
import React from 'react';
import VimeoIframe from 'react-native-vimeo-iframe';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <VimeoIframe
      videoId={123456789}
      disableDebugLog={true}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Once you have added the disableDebugLog prop, the debug log will no longer be displayed.